# Syntax errors in a bash script executed from tcsh

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote the line below in order to verify if the first or second fields of a list of numbers are equal to 146.

I want to run the line from `tcsh`, with one line interpreted by `bash`.

What's the problem here?

```
echo $numbers
146 146 0 16 16 10 42 12 10 32 32 3 2 32 26
tcsh

bash -c 'for i in 1 2; do if [ 146 = `echo $numbers | cut -f$i  -d' ' ` ]; then echo "NUM is OK "; fi done'
```

The errors:

```
` ]; then echo "NUM is OK "; fi done: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
` ]; then echo "NUM is OK "; fi done: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: try `"146" ==` instead of `146 =`

Comment: not work ( the same problem )

Comment: So the problem is with single quotes you used to wrap your whole commands. It prevents back-quotes to be replaced with its result. Try this: `bash -c "for i in 1 2; do if [ 146 = \`echo $numbers | cut -f$i  -d' ' \` ]; then echo 'NUM is OK '; fi done"`

Comment: yes now its works thx

Comment: Please don't cross-post (http://superuser.com/questions/490613/linux-write-bash-one-line-syntax), it makes a mess and scatters answers all over the place. Post on **one** site, the one you think is most appropriate, and the community will move it elsewhere if there is a better home for your question.

Comment: An alternative: `awk '{N=146} $1!=N && $2!=N {exit 1}'` - will give exit status 0 if first AND/OR second field are/is 146, and exit status 1 otherwise. Since you fork `cut` anyway, you could just use a tool more suited to begin with :-) . I'm guessing this is something that is looped over many lines, so the `awk` way will probably be much more efficient as the size increases. It should also be POSIX universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with single quotes (used to wrap the whole set of commands). The difference between single quotes and double quotes is that in double quotes variables and back-quote commands will be replaced with their value, but in single quotes the string will be treated as is.

You may use:

```
bash -c "for i in 1 2; do if [ 146 = `echo $numbers | cut -f$i -d' ' ` ]; then echo 'NUM is OK '; fi done"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple problems with your "script", the main one being the `'` which would need some form of escaping. Within backticks inside a hard-quoted string this gets hairy.

You could avoid this completely by using `$()` instead of backticks, and not using hard quotes for the delimiter:

```
... if [ 146 -eq $(echo $numbers | cut -f$i -d\ ) ]; then ...
```

Note that `-eq` is the appropriate predicate for numbers, and that `$numbers` will need to be exported for this to work at all.

Writing a proper script and calling it from `tcsh` would be best though.

Answer (score 0):

How about `grep`? Is this a static problem, or will the numbers and criterion change?

If it's static:

```
echo $numbers | grep -c '(^146\s)|(^\d+\s146\s)'
```

This returns 0 or 1 depending on if there is a match.

This isn't tested, but it should match first or second field.  There are other patterns which may be more efficient, but should be close to working.

Comment: You can use `grep -q` to return exit status 0 if a match is found and exit status 1 if it is not found, which integrates better in shell scripts, such as `if grep -q "mypattern" myfile; then ...`.

Comment: In this case, the question was to find if the first OR the second number was 146. Your pattern only matches if BOTH are 146. Also, you should have a `^` where you have a `$`.